# Assigning New FileReader to Object Doesn't Fire Onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader

Why does this work:

```
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    alert("work");
  };
```

But when I use my namespaced object to assign it, it doesn't work:

```
  nameSpace.cropper.reader = new FileReader();
  nameSpace.cropper.reader.onload = function(event) {
    alert("work");
  };
```

What am I misunderstanding about how objects work?

Comment: Throwing it out there.  `nameSpace.cropper` exists before those two lines execute?

Comment: Yeah, I instantiate with `nameSpace.cropper = nameSpace.cropper || {};` at the top. I'm noticing now though that it seems now like it's breaking if I remove `reader.readAsText(file);` from the end of it...so maybe it isn't a problem of assignment?

Comment: Dunno, but from what you have here, if the nameSpace.cropper already exists, I don't see anything wrong with your logic syntatically.

Comment: `reader.readAsText(file)` is the whole point, that's where you tell the reader to do its job :) If you remove that, of course the event will never fire.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/05Lhca7g/4/  runs fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to define the objects properly and the second option would work too.

Make sure that you are calling the `onload()` method on an event.

```js
var nameSpace = new Object();
nameSpace.cropper = new Object();

nameSpace.cropper.reader = new FileReader();
nameSpace.cropper.reader.onload = function(event) {
   alert("work");
};

nameSpace.cropper.reader.onload();
```

Comment: OOOOOh I can't believe I did that. I assumed the onload event just fired when it was ready. I wasn't calling it yet, though, so of course it wasn't firing. Thanks, I should be able to round that out now, then!

Comment: Does the onload not fire automatically when you read a file?  Figured it was an event handler that did not have to be called explicitly

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload   Yeah, it's an event handler.  You shouldn't have to explicitly invoke it

Comment: @Taplar I mentioned that, you will need to call it on an event. Just to demo it, I called that explicitly.

Comment: It's working fine now, I just misunderstood how the onload method of the FileReader worked.